# App with self-contained videos

Tags: android, ios, video

Client wants an app, ideally with the videos self-contained, so no hosting or streaming issues. There will be about eighty 1-min videos. How practical is this on Android and iOS? Should I encourage the client to use streaming or some other solution instead?

Comment: doable. assets are made for this.

Comment: Can your device store the eighty videos in question? If the answer is yes, put them in the assets folder. From there you can fetch/manipulate them any way you want...

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on weather you want your users to be able to use the app while offline or not.
If you need you users to be able to view the videos when offline you have to include them in your app. 80 one minute videos, when properly compressed and encoded to take as little storage as possible - should not present a problem (they should take less than 100MB storage).

Good luck!